# How to use [$(DatabaseName)] as a string in an insert

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

I have a post-deployment script in an SSDT project that needs to log the name of the database it's being deployed to. I'm trying to declare the string and set it equal to `[$(DatabaseName)]` but no matter how I've tried it so far, it keeps wanting to interpret the variable as a column name.

I've tried escaping quotes around it, casting it, using `QUOTENAAME`, etc. with no luck. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**

Here's a trimmed-down version how I'm trying to use the variable

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(50) = [$(DatabaseName)]
EXEC usp_ScriptLog
@DatabaseName
```

`usp_ScriptLog` is a pretty simple stored procedure that inserts a row into a table containing data about the script being run.

Comment: can you show your code? I am unclear as to exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the name of the database that you are deploying to in the post-deploy script then you don't need to use a cmd variable - you can use plain t-sql such as:

`Select db_name()`

I would always favour plain t-sql over a sql cmd variable as adding it affects every build and deploy step.

Comment: hi i added some extra comments

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to quote it normally, play around in SSMS in SQLCMD Mode its more fully featured than VS but for this purpose i think it works the same.

> :setvar DatabaseName "MyDB"
>
> Declare @Test Table (Value1 varchar(50))
>
> Insert Into @Test (Value1) Values ('[$(DatabaseName)]')
>
> Select * From @Test

This is for string, though it will depend what you're doing with it in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if you delete those brackets maybe it will work. Because database and column names can not include special characters except "_".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could wrap single quote character codes (39) around the parameter when inserting your row, that'll force it to see it as a string value. I don't think it's compulsory but I make use of sp_executesql in this case, presumably from your stored procedure (if it's not viable to use within your script):

```
Declare @your_query nvarchar(1000)='
INSERT INTO [Table] (database_name)
SELECT '+char(39)+@DatabaseName+char(39)

EXEC sp_executesql @your_query
```

Runtime equivalent:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (database_name)
SELECT 'YourParameterValue'
```

Seen as a value, not a column name.